# React component not rendering in root

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

I am trying to display a simple form using react but I get the error "Target container is not a DOM element" despite the fact that the root element is definitely a DOM element as I have check using console.

edit : Importing form  'react-dom' and using 'render' works fine but I  cannot seem to get it work other wise

Here is the form component

```
import React from 'react';

export default function StudentForm()
{
  return (
            <form>
                //some stuff
            </form>
          )
}
```

My index file

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import StudentForm from './App';



const root = document.getElementById('root');


ReactDOM.createRoot(<StudentForm/>,root);
```

Here is my index.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your `index.html` file look like? And is `ReactDOM` exported from `'react-dom/client'` or just `react-dom`?

Comment: I have edited the question to address this and have included index.html file, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't have a element with id `root` in your index.html, please add the following tag in your index.html,

`<div id="root" />`

Comment: I do have the root element in index.html, I updated the question to include the file as well. Thanks for response anyway

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StudentForm />
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your main or index script to HTML.

```
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="module" src="/src/index.tsx"></script>
```